# Microsoft Access - if I modify my Query, will the form also change

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I always base my form's on a query.

example : `qry_customerInformation` & `frm_customerInformation`

But lately I been force to remake my forms everytime, I notice a small error in my query, by maybe not sorting correctly or I forgot to display a specific column. It seems very inefficient by my part. Shouldn't the form update itself, if a new field or sort is added to the query it is based on? am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your Forms are created, you have the option to Edit them. It does not necessarily mean that you have to remake the whole form. Once the Form is created, you can right click the Form on the navigation pane and select Design view where you will be given several options via the Property sheet. This is where you will have **Order By**, **Filter**, several other fields if you wish to add, you use the **Add existing fields**

Answer (score 1):

The Form will not `Auto-Update` if the underlying Query is modified.

Consider these two cases

`Case A`: New fields added to the query

Result: No effect on the form , Form will run with out errors

`Case B:` One or more columns referenced on the form  are modified

Result: You will see the error saying that xyz column is modified or non-existent